# Can you get DOM element representing a pop up window without var newWindow = window.open in Chrome (works but only when Dev Tools on)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom

Using a pretty clunky framework for a website, when a user opens a document, two pop ups are generated to support split screen. The first pop up is generated from a user clicking on a table, the second pop up is generated from the first pop up. However the method in which the user submits the first pop up (which closes the second pop up based on an onbeforeunload event does not have access to the variable that represents the second pop up.

From what I have read the below should be a way to grab a reference to the secondPopUp from the firstPopUp (since window.open is originally run on the firstPopUp) as long as I have the windowName and am in same domain.

'''var existingWindow= window.open('','secondPopUp');'''

However this solution weirdly only works when Google Chrome developer tools are turned on.

Is there anyway to get this to work without having to rewrite how the window.opens are called? Seeing it work with Chrome Dev Tools on makes me think there must be some trick.

Comment: Are all the pages on the same origin (protocol + host + port)? Browsers restrict the data that cross-origin pages can get from each other (e.g. no direct access to each other's `window` object and so their variables). Can you use `postMessage` instead?

Comment: They are same protocol + host + port. The annoying part is it works when F12 has been used, but fails when not used. The core of the issue is I need to find dimensions of both pop ups when a user closes these windows (on a onbeforeunload event) and async message calls don't consistently finish when used in onbeforeunload so I am trying to find the dimensions elsewhere so they can be saved (in this case on a button click on popup one)